# Google App Engine: How to create sub domain/ sub directory

Tags: google-app-engine

being new to google app engine and a slow learner in the new python language, i would like to ask this question. On the main page (abc.appspot.com) i have a button (eg: About) and I want to create a sub domain where when i click on "about" , it will navigate me to abc.appspot.com/about

Tried playing ard with yaml (which i suspect i should be editing this) but there's error~ any guidance anyone can provide? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

for a sub directory just create an html in your war folder. After deploying you can go to yourapp.appspot.com/yourwebpage

if you need something more...

python:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles

java:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml